# Android SimpleDateFormat.format(Date) issue

Tags: java, android, date, format, simpledateformat

I don't know if anyone has encountered the same issue I did today: using the SimpleDateFormat.format(Date) has been appending weird "00" in the output string. 
Here's my code:

```
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm", Locale.getDefault());
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d(log_tag, "current date time is"+dateformatter.format(new Date(timestamp)));
    }
```

So the 100 print out on my screen is a combination of

```
2013-10-10-hh-mm
2013-0010-10-hh-mm
2013-10-0010-hh-mm
etc.
```

It's appending "00" in front of month/day/hour/minute. It's really strange. I'm curious how come it did this?

Comment: What is the locale of your OS?

Comment: Please give precise examples of your output - ideally just log the string and then copy/paste the output from logcat.

Comment: I didn't use the exact code. But the simplified output is: 2013-10-10-05-16, 2013-10-10-05-16, 2013-10-10-05-16, 2013-10-10-05-16, 2013-10-0010-05-16, 2013-10-0010-05-16, 2013-10-0010-05-16, 2013-10-10-05-16, 2013-0010-10-05-16, 2013-10-10-0005-16, 2013-10-10-05-0016, 2013-10-10-05-16, 2013-10-10-05-16, 2013-10-10-0005-16, 2013-10-10-05-16, 2013-10-10-05-16, 2013-10-10-05-16. Something like this

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this.

Comment: There might be something in my current code. Maybe too many threads. Tested it with a clean project it was fine.